# How to supply args from the argparse to an external program call via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, argparse

In a task, I need to call an external program that run on terminal via python. This external program has lots of positional and optional arguments.

Here is the sample code developed sofar:

```
def multi_character_parameter():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('b',
                        help="Execute tests with browser 'firefox' or 'chrome', or 'ALL")
    parser.add_argument('C', help="Execute tests in cloud 'aws' or 'azure'")
    parser.add_argument(
        'c', help="Clear output and temp directory before executing tests")
    parser.add_argument('d', help="Check syntax for test data")
    parser.add_argument("--upper-case", default=False, action="store_true")
...
args = parser.parse_args()

def my_external_program():
 subprocess.call(["external_program"])
```

Could someone please suggest:

1. How to supply  these args  to the **external_program** called via subprocess.

i.e. upon running say `python script.py some_args`, these `some_args` will be supplied to the `external_program` function for execution as `external_program some_args`.

2. What would be the better way to structure the code if the `args` specified in the code needs to be used at other parts of the code.

Comment: Are you looking to pass the arguments exactly as they were passed to your script, or is there some sort of mapping from the parameters you defined for your script to the parameters required on the external program?

Comment: Why not let `external_program` decide if the arguments are right or wrong, otherwise you will need the same logic in your script and need to maintain it every time the other changes

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano although that's a question OP should definitely consider, it's still a good question if someone wants to limit what can be passed in this case, or perhaps modify a few of the passed parameters. In the latter case, OP might consider only restricting the parameters they care about, but pass through any additional parameters unchecked.

Comment: @Grismar that's for the suggestions. Each of these arguments will be mapped with some sort of options that a user can provide. Like `C` alias `Cloud` values can be AWS or AZURE.. etc..

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano The `external_program` has some sort of syntax/pattern in suppying the inputs. The idea with this script is to just stick with the `python` itself for simplicity and the script supplying (most commonly used) user provided args to the `external_program`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the variable `args`, you can access any of the arguments using dot notation.

I have edited your code to demonstrate this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
 
import argparse
import subprocess

def multi_character_parameter():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--b',
                        help="Execute tests with browser 'firefox' or 'chrome', or 'ALL",
                        required=False,
                        default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--C', help="Execute tests in cloud 'aws' or 'azure'",
        required=False, default=False)   
    parser.add_argument(
        '--c', help="Clear output and temp directory before executing tests",
        required=False, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--d', help="Check syntax for test data", required=False, default=False)
    parser.add_argument("--upper-case", action="store_true", required=False, default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def my_external_program(args):
    print(args)
    b = str(args.b)
    C = str(args.C)
    c = str(args.c)
    d = str(args.d)
    upper_case = str(args.upper_case)
    subprocess.call(["echo", b,C,c,d,upper_case ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = multi_character_parameter()
    my_external_program(multi_character_parameter())
```

Now to run it `chmod +x test.py`

`./test.py`

The stdout is presented to show access to the args (the external program was subbed out for `echo` as the program:

```
Namespace(b=False, C=False, c=False, d=False, upper_case=False)
False False False False False
```

Comment: This isn't going to work, `upper_case` will be something like `True` and `external_command`  won't recognize that

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano you are right. I have debugged and edited the script.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to literally pass all the arguments:

```
import sys

subprocess.call(["external_program"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

This takes all the arguments passed to the script (except the first, which is the script's name) and just appends them to the argument you already provided, the name of the external program - and probably works as expected.

So, if you were to run `python your_script.py 1 2 3 4` (which matches your specified argument requirements), it would call `external_program 1 2 3 4`.

The more general answer is that you should just provide a list of arguments to `subprocess.call`, as described in [the documentation for `subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api) - "`args` should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string or path-like object."

Since you provide no information on exactly what mapping you're after, or how the arguments to your script translate to arguments for the external program, it's not possible to be a lot more specific - other than saying you need to construct a sequence of arguments to pass to the call.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to limit or restrict the arguments passed to `external_program` you can do something like this

```
allowed_args = ['--upper-case', 'b', 'c', 'C', 'd']
subprocess.run(['external_program'] + list(set(sys.argv).intersection(allowed_args)))
```